# How to manage .SO files android studio?

Tags: java, android, opencv

Every time I try to run my app, it always gets this error.

> Process: com.example.jude.prototype, PID: 18048
>                                                                               java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", ] couldn't find
>   "libopencv_java.so"

But I already imported the "`libopencv_java.so`" under the jniLibs.

What should I do?

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saefq.png)

Comment: Picture attached named "Problem"

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, lib `libopencv_java.so` was not found... In other words, it was not added to your APK file.

1. Check if a file named `libopencv_java.so` was added to the jniLibs folder
2. Check if your build gradle is including the .so files

   ```
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.so'], dir: 'jniLibs')
   ```
3. In Build->Analyze APK, open your APK and check if `libopencv_java.so` can be found under `lib` folder

If you can find lib `libopencv_java.so` in your APK, it means your project is not being compiled right (or files structure is wrong). This way, you must share your build.gradle file.

Comment: Already did the 'implementation fileTree(include: ['*.so'], dir: 'jniLibs')' but nothing seem to happen. I also used the compile fileTree(include ['*.so'], dir: 'jniLibs')' didn't work also.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed the issue. However it brings up a new error

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library
>   "../../lib/libtbb.so" not found

library is already on apk, but however it doesn't get recognize. Why?

Comment: I forgot that I'm using javacpp.jar, and javacv.jar. compileSdk 25

Comment: Did you find any answer? Please share with me

Comment: @JosephBorja, what did you mean about compileSdk 25 ?

Comment: @Innocent, sorry for the delayed replies. As far as I know, I used maven repository on this.